# How to share USB 3.0 Hard Disk directly over a local network

Tags: ethernet, usb-drive, nas, data-sharing

Like the title object, I'm looking for a way to share my external hard disk (which have a usb 3.0 connectors) over a local network without a computer. I think that a NAS adapter should be the perfect solution but I don't want to spend too many money on that so I'm looking for a cheaper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some kind of standalone Linux board with network capability is likely the cheapest option here. It does require you to google setup details, but is a very elastic option when it comes to what you can use it for in future. It might be harder to benefit from full USB 3.0 throughput, so if you care about performance, better to invest in some ready solution.

Personally I can recommend having a look at RaspberryPi model B board for that purpose: https://www.raspberrypi.org/